# DC Motor - Laptop Charger

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I have a DC motor rated at 12 V which in its current application draws around 1.5 A. Currently I am using a fairly bulky DC power supply and wondered if there is any reason why I can't use an appropriate laptop power supply with say a 12 VDC and 3 A output rating?

Would this work?

Comment: Motors can generate high voltage spikes - the laptop supply may need some protection from the motor!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't connect your laptop as well, so the total current drawn from the charger doesn't exceed the 3A limit, this is okay I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Motors can draw well over their nameplate current rating during startup.  And laptop supplies immediately shutdown when you exceed their current rating.  So one way this won't work is if the motor draws >3A during start and the laptop supply immediately kicks out.

But it will probably work fine.